# How to import a .txt file in sqlite by relative path (no local path)?

Tags: sqlite

I know to import text by local path
.import local path/filename.txt tablename.

How to use relative path?

Update: I changed directory which resolved the "relative path". To change the directory, use .cd:
      sqlite> .cd /Users/yourname/directory/

Comment: Can you include the code you are currently using to load a file into SQLite?

Comment: .separator ","
sqlite> .import text.txt myTable;
Error: cannot open "text.txt"   My task asked me not to use local path to import the text.txt file

Comment: Why not just use the full path?  To make your code work, you'll need to find out what the relative path is being used by SQLite.  Then, place your text file there.

Comment: I figured it out. I set the directory.

Comment: You may answer your own question, and maybe this would help others.

Comment: can u update the answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Putting the text file in the same folder where sqlite3.exe is present will work. (no need to give path then, just text file name will suffice)